# Ошибка при инсталяции ВСЕГО в ubuntu (не только apache2)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Все время устанавливал программы через консоль, или Менеджер Приложений Ubuntu, но понадобился apache2 для php...

Я пытался установить apache2 на ubuntu, но мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install».
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 apache2 : Зависит: apache2-utils (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.4)
           Зависит: apache2-data (= 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.4) но он не будет установлен
 gsignond-plugin-oauth : Зависит: gsignond но он не будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt --fix-broken install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).
```

что делать?

Comment: apt --fix-broken install надеюсь попытались выполнить? а это  - apt-get -f install? :-)

Comment: Пытался, не помогло, пишет: При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gsignond_1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb

Comment: я бы снёс `gsignond-plugin-oauth`/`gsignond`, а потом [полу]вручную разрулил бы зависимости `aptitude`'ом...

Comment: Не работает:  dpkg: ошибка при обработке архива /var/cache/apt/archives/gsignond_1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 попытка перезаписать «/usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.google.code.AccountsSSO.SingleSignOn.service», который уже имеется в пакете signond 8.59+17.10.20170606-0ubuntu1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gsignond_1.1.0~r509+pkg4~daily~ubuntu5.0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я удалил gsignond-plugin-oauth и все работает, может другим поможет?

```
sudo apt remove gsignond-plugin-oauth
```